# How to align text under image with the same height using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have two images side by side that I want to make the same height using flexbox and I want to align the text under the image. Can someone please help me ??

This is my code :

```css
 
 .row{
  display:flex;
  }
  .cell img{
      width:150px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
  <img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-589121_1280.jpg"></div>
<p class="project1info">
Featuring allows a user to search a musical artist and view a list of collaboraters they have worked with.</p>

<div class="cell">
  <img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-1882120_1280-1.png"></div>
<p class="project1info">
Featuring allows a user to search a musical artist and view a list of collaboraters they have worked with.</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add screenshot , in your codes images are in same height!

Answer (score 0):

You can give no in height percentage, So you get it in pixels.

Your case you try it:-

```
 .wp-block-image img{
     width:100%;
     height:320px;
     object-fit:cover;
  }
```

This code will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Make your outer element for fix height and keep image height 100%.

```
.wp-block-image{
  width:100%;
  height:320px;
}
```